# Figure it out the subnet mask

Tags: c, calculator, subnet

I have to write a program that find out the subnet mask.
I have two input, the first one is the class indicator (A,B,C).
The second one is a number,which shows the number of subnets.
The output is the subnet mask.

For example :

> A 4
>   subnet mask :255.192.0.0

Without IP address I dont know how to do it.
I appreciate the answers,Thanks.

Comment: You definitely don't need the IP address. The class gives you the initial size (/8 /16 /24) and the # of subnets divides that further.

Comment: can you show us how you was trying to do it?

Comment: I haven't started yet because the problem has alredy caught me :/

Answer (score 0):

I can explain you what I understood:
For class indicator:

```
A -> 255.X.X.X
B -> 255.255.X.X
C -> 255.255.255.X
```

The number of subnets will define what are the 'X'.

In your example, you need 4 subnets; so if you consider the second segment, you get in binary for each subnet:

```
00YY YYYY
01YY YYYY
10YY YYYY
11YY YYYY
```

This means that the mask is (still in binary): 1111 1111.1100 0000.0000 0000.0000 0000 (you get your 255.192.0.0)